# Open a port with vb?

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone please share a simple code for VB 2008 to open a port. I would like it to be just like [utorrent](http://www.utorrent.com) how you can change the listening port for data transfer. thanks a lot if you can help me!

Answer (score 2):

As Avner indicated, uTorrent *is not* simple code. If you'd like to do anything on that level, then you've got a lot to do.

Here is a simple sample socket program you can build on.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the host name or IP Address to connect to:")
        Dim hostName = Console.ReadLine().Trim()
        If hostName.Length = 0 Then
            ' use the local computer if there is no host provided
            hostName = Dns.GetHostName()
        End If

        Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = Nothing
        ' parse and select the first IPv4 address
        For Each address In Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList
            If (address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork) Then
                ipAddress = address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ' you will have to check beyond this point to ensure
        ' there is a valid address before connecting

        Dim client = New TcpClient()
        Try
            ' attempt to connect on the address
            client.Connect(ipAddress, 80)

            ' do whatever you want with the connection


        Catch ex As SocketException
            ' error accessing the socket
        Catch ex As ArgumentNullException
            ' address is null
            ' hopefully this will never happen
        Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            ' port must be from 0 to 64k (&HFFFF)
            ' check and ensure you've used the right port
        Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
            ' the tcpClient has been disposed
            ' hopefully this will never happen
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' any other exception I haven't dreamt of

        Finally
            ' close the connection

            ' the TcpClient.Close() method does not actually close the
            ' underlying connection. You have to close it yourself.
            ' http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B821625
            client.GetStream().Close()

            ' then close the client's connection
            client.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Be aware that socket programming is quite complicated and you will have to thoroughly test your code for all edge cases.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

uTorrent is anything but a "simple code". It's a complicated application with a lot of network logic going on beyond just opening a port and pushing bits in and out of it.

But your starting point for low-level communications handling would be the [`System.Net.Sockets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) namespace, which contains the `Socket` class. It allows low-level control such as opening a port, listening for connections and handling them yourself.

[Here's](http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_socket_programming.htm) a tutorial about Socket programming in VB.NET, but you'll probably find more information if you search for "C# Socket tutorial". C# syntax is a bit different than VB.NET, but it uses the same classes and the same concepts, so you'll probably be able to apply the lessons to your own code.

Comment: thanks, but i would like it in VB.